# Where to start learning SOAP Web Services (in java)?

Tags: web-services, soap, soap-client, restful-architecture

I have been searching a good tutorial and resource to brush up SOAP web services knowledge. Even though there are lots of resources I found none of them truly solid to grab the main knowledge. Especially in Java, there are multiple approaches to do the same thing. I want to know what are the main advantages on choosing one approach to another, and where to decided to choose one to another. I appreciate if someone can share their experience on learning web services, specifically SOAP. If you have REST knowledge or if you can share a good valid resource, that would be useful for future reads. Any key reads and/or well covered tutorial will be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, SOAP java knowledge is very scattered and that's one of the reasons why [Java EE 6 Web Services Developer Certified Expert](https://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=5001&get_params=p_exam_id:1Z0-897) is so hard.

You can start with the Oracle [official webservices tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/partwebsvcs.htm#BNAYK).

There are also [good online resources](http://www.benchresources.net/web-services/metro-jax-ws-soap-tutorials/).

You would also have to read some old books and the SOAP specs.

Also some good [youtube videos](https://javabrains.io/topics/javaee/).

Try [blogs](https://vvirlan.wordpress.com/tag/jax-ws/).

Books:

- Java and SOAP. Building Web Services in Java
- Java Web Services: Up and Running, 2nd Edition

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely take a look.